# feh conditional zoom

Tags: feh, image-viewer

Is it possible to make `feh` do `--zoom fill` only if height or width of the image is less than a specified value during a slideshow so that it won't try to fill a smaller image(less than the dimensions specified) on the screen?

Also, is it possible to do transition effects on `feh`?